# Is it possible to use Jackpot outside of NetBeans, without NetBeans projects?

Tags: java, netbeans

I know there is a Jackpot API http://jackpot.netbeans.org/docs/org-netbeans-modules-jackpot/overview-summary.html for programmatic access the the rules engine, has anyone had success seperating this from NetBeans itself? So it can operate on any Java source files?

Comment: The link in question is broken. Can you provide updated link, so the question won't end up dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, but the answer, sadly, is no.

http://netbeans.org/community/articles/interviews/tom-ball-interview.html

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is nothing to stop you grabbing out the jar files and calling it directly. You just might need to bring a lot of netbeans with it.